# how extract html markup tags

Tags: html, tags, markup

Is out there a text editor, software, script, code, sniper or something similar to generate an output similar to the one on the picture from a html file?
In other works something to output only the html markup tags.
Thank you for helping me out.
[output sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X62m.jpg)
[Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT61M.jpg)

Here is a Before and After image of what I need so you guys can understand what I'm looking for. I'm no so good detailing things. Thanks

Comment: I don't know of one, but what you can do is parse the text and replace anything found between quotes (`"something"`) with white space (`" "`).

Comment: Thank you but actually I don't need to replace anything between quotes, what I need is to get rid of everything between tags <> </>.

Comment: So the output sample you linked is incorrect?

Comment: the sample is just a sample and is correct.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Try building a regular expression that catches text (char/num/punct) between `<>` and excludes text that isn't. Give me a few minutes to whip up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a tool for this task. I think it's an interesting idea to study the structure of an html file like this. I needed this several times as well, so I wrote a tiny command line tool, that should do the job:

**html_skeleton** (https://github.com/antonharald/html_skeleton)

---

What it does:

1. Read The File
2. Parse the HTML structure to a virtual DOM
3. Recursively visit all HTML Elements. For each of them: Remove the attribute values and in case there are no children: Remove it's text content.
4. Transform the manipulated DOM into HTML code and print it.

I didn't have time to test it that much, so would be nice to hear if it worked for you.

Comment: Thank you Anton. Yes, it worked for me. It is a great tool and could be even more if can be attached as a bookmarklet to a browser to process remote files instead of having the files in localhost. Thank you for sharing this tool.